# Is "this" really a keyword in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, this

I have a working piece of code until I added a last property to it. I know the issues of this in javascript. But this is something I have never encounter before.

```
var name = "John Dane";
var age = 24;

var person = {
  id: 'emp133y1998',
  name, age,
  forEach: function(action) {
    for (var prop in this) {
      if(prop === 'forEach') continue;
      action(this[prop]);
    }
  },
  this: name +" "+ age
};

person.forEach(e => say(e));
```

If `this` is keyword how can we use it as a property name. Even stranger thing is I can actually access it `person.this` like this. But unfortunately my `forEach` method broke after this. So I removed it. I'm still in learning phase. Can anyone explain what is actually happening here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this Yes it's a keyword and no you should not try and use it as anything other than it's intended use

Comment: That it's a keyword has no impact on what you can do with it. Keywords are defined by the spec, and what you can or can't do is defined by the same spec. There's nothing that universally demands any particular limitation on the use of a keyword. It's all language semantics. So in short, you can use a keyword as a property name because the spec says so.

Comment: code works for me

Comment: @dandavis I'm using node and it's not working! Maybe Node Bug I'm not sure still.

Comment: @squint I'm not offending you. But I don't think any language would allow the use of keywords like identifier. There's a reason they are reserved! And javascript is no exception. The problem was different with my code.

Comment: @scrappedcola Thank You! It was helpful. `this` is indeed a keyword. :)

Comment: JavaScript is an exception WRT property identifiers. The point is that the spec governs what can and can't be done. So if you can do it, it's because the spec allows it. And if you think about it, `this` is actually both a keyword *and* an identifier. It's very much like an automatic, immutable function parameter in JS. Main difference is how you set its value. I don't know what problem in the code you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a reserved keywords [as of ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keyword) specification.

The language allow you to declare a property name with a reserved keywords using bracket syntax or not as mention by @squint.

Notes: Naked use of reserved words is supported from ES5 onwards not before.

Example valid for browser enviroment:

```js
// this code works on before ES5 and onward
// this bracket syntax for maximum portability of your code
var obj = {};
obj['this'] = 'hello i am this'; // bracket syntax
obj['for'] = 'hello i am for';
alert(obj['this']);
alert(obj['for']);
```

```js
// this code works on ES5 and onward
var obj = {};
obj.this = 'hello i am this'; // bracket syntax
obj.for = 'hello i am for';
alert(obj.this);
alert(obj.for);
```

IMO: I suggest to DO NOT use `this` or other reserved keywords as a name of a property as could create subtitle bugs and could be confusing to human and build tools.

Comment: It's clear to me now. Actually it works in browser but I'm using node in which it breaks. Maybe the `this` reference gets changed. It's a guess though, I'm not sure. And one more thing I just realized that all properties of object are actually keys i.e. string keys and inside of strings anything is allowed the compiler won't interfere in that. After all in javascript objects are nothing but `key: value` `===` `'key': value` pairs. This thought struck my mind when I saw JSON!

Comment: You don't need bracket syntax to use keywords as property names. `obj.this;` and `obj.for;` will work just fine

Comment: Naked use of reserved words is supported from ES5 onwards not before. For code portability bracket notation helps :) - I made an edit to my answer. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: That's true. Probably not an issue for the OP since ES6 features are being used already. ES3 is becoming a distant memory.